# craft with -ing or not?

Tags: word-choice, differences, ing

I've seen 'coding craft': http://www.codingcraft.co.uk/
and 'hire craft': http://hirecraft.com/
what's the correct version? why not 'hiring craft'? what's the difference?

Comment: It's a company's name. They can name it whatever they want. There is no "correct" version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coding craft is a correct phrase; it means 'the craft of coding' as you said.Hire craft is correct as well; it means  skill or ability to hire.It can of course be written hiring craft also.As you know hire can be a verb or a noun; see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hire:

```
    verb (used with object), hired, hiring.
    1.
    to engage the services of (a person or persons) for wages or other payment:
    to hire a clerk.
    2.
    to engage the temporary use of at a set price; rent:
    to hire a limousine.
    noun
    3.
    the act of hiring.
    4.
    the state or condition of being hired.
    5.
    the price or compensation paid or contracted to be paid
 for the temporary use of something or for personal services or labor; pay:
    The laborer is worthy of his hire.
    6.
    Informal. a person hired or to be hired:
    Most of our new hires are college-educated.
```

Craft can also be a verb and a noun; http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crafting:

```
* Skill in doing or making something, as in the arts; proficiency.


* tr.v. (craft·ed, craft·ing, crafts)
To make or construct (something) with care or ingenuity.
```

Finally code can be a verb and a noun; please see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coding.

Comment: thanks! why does it matter that those words can be a noun and a verb? craft should be use like noun + craft, right?

Comment: Yes you can use noun+ craft:coding craft.Then you may join them to have a web name, codingcraft, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Coding craft is the name of a company so they can name it what they would like and it does not matter (as long as they have copyrights).

Comment: i know it's a company's name but can't you say 'the craft of coding' or 'coding craft' or 'code craft'? is it a correct phrase?